# Split a dataframe column with regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to split a column that has a specific delimiter like: '|'.

My data looks like this, I have ONLY ONE COLUMN named  "ID" that contains those strings that I want to split based on delimiter " | "

```
ID accountsummary            | Name: Report Suite Totals 

ID activity                  | Name: Activity
```

I've tried with 2 different approaches:

1. ```
   dataframe_elements_int[['ID', 'Name']] = \
       dataframe_elements_int['ID'].str.rsplit('|', expand=True, n=1)
   ```

Which gives me the following error: `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`

2. ```
   dataframe_final[['Id','Name']] = \
       dataframe_elements_int['ID'].str.extract('(\w*)\|(\w*)', expand=True)
   ```

Which gives me the following error: `ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups`

Comment: Please don't attach images. Write it as formatted text.

Comment: @MayankPorwal got it!

Comment: Can you please attach a sample of the dataframe with column names?

Comment: I think extract need a named group. See my answer below for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
df=dataframe_elements_int
#split the column
df['new_ID'], df['Name'] = df['ID'].str.split('|').str
#filtering the Name and ID 
df['Name']=df['Name'].str.extract(r'((?<=Name:).*$)', expand=True)
df['new_ID']=df['new_ID'].str.extract(r'((?<=ID).*$)',expand=True)
```

Comment: This error occured: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Comment: I assume dataframe_elements_int is a dataframe. Can you check `dataframe_elements_int['ID'].dtypes` and check if it comes as object datatype

Comment: Yep. You're right. I've converted it with astype(str) and then your response worked! Thank you!! Just one more quick question: If I would want to grab only that characters after "ID" and "Name" for each observation. How do I do it?

Comment: You can use `df['ID_new']=df['new_ID'].str.extract(r'ID:\s*(\w+\s*\w*)+', expand=True) `

Comment: `df['Name_stripped']=df['Name'].str.extract(r'Name:\s*(\w+\s*\w*)+', expand=True)`  Glad I could be of help. Happy coding! :D

Comment: Like this the whitespaces remain in ID and name and "Name:" is part of the Name column. Is that intended?

Comment: @Sreekiran In some cases "Name" is cut too soon. In some cases name is like this: "" Name: Display Mode(Action Tracking) (v9) " or "" Name: First Touch Marketing Channel Detail". Using your function Name_stripped is like: "Display Mode" or "First Touch". How to deal with this?

Comment: I have edited answer using a generalised approach in regex. Check it out now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following Regex:

```
ID\s+(\w+)\s+|\s+Name:\s+(.*)$
```

If you want to use extract, do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=["ID accountsummary            | Name: Report Suite Totals",
                        "ID activity                  | Name: Activity"], columns=["ID"])
pattern = r"ID\s+(?P<IDnew>\w+)"
df["NewId"] = df["ID"].str.extract(pattern)
pattern = r"Name:\s+(?P<Name>.*)$"
df["Name"] = df["ID"].str.extract(pattern)
df.drop(["ID"], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.rename({"NewId": "ID"})
```

Comment: I used this line of code: dataframe_final[['Id','Name']] = dataframe_elements_int['ID'].str.extract(r'ID\s+(\w+)\s+|\s+Name:\s+(.*)$', expand=True)   And It gives we 'Nan' values everywhere